# Why is swap() sometimes implemented by passing an array?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, computer-science

In some comp-sci papers and tests, I see swap() implemented like so:

```
void swap(int x, int y, int *a)
{
    int t = a[x];
    a[x] = a[y];
    a[y] = t;
}
```

Why not simply implement it like so:

```
void swap(int& x, int& y)
{
    int t = x;
    x = y;
    y = t;
}
```

Is the idea to the former to make the calling code cleaner, by not having to index into the array for the first two arguments? I realize it's not a very important question, since we should be using std::swap(), but I'm still curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all programming languages support calling by reference. For instance, the latter way of doing `swap` doesn't apply to Java.

In books containing pseudo-code, usually there's a convention that arrays and pointers are not copied when passed and everything else is copied in a function call.  The former way requires no special explanation about the way arguments are passed.

Regarding your final point about cleanliness, it's not so much different: in the former case, your call to swap would be simply: `swap(i, j, a);` whereas in the latter, you'll have to `swap(a[i], a[j]);`, introducing some brackets in the expression.

Comment: Java? Is it a programming language? ;)

Comment: In the case of Java, it's not just call-by-reference but infix pointers that are not supported. Most (all?) garbage-collected languages forbid them because they are a mess to handle for the GC. These languages naturally drive you to write in the style of the first snippet in the question.

Comment: @Pascal: C# supports `ref` parameters.

Comment: Does that include references to a location inside a bloc (e.g. to an element of an array)? If it does, it surely is implemented by passing a pointer to the bloc and an offset at the bytecode level.

Comment: @Pascal: CIL has an instruction called [`ldelema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldelema.aspx) which takes an array and an index from the stack and pushes a managed reference (which is natively supported by the instruction set) to the specific array element to the stack, which is passed to the function. After the reference is conceived, it won't matter that it's an array element or a field or a local variable. You can swap a local variable with an object field or an array element in a uniform way.

Answer (score 2):

Your second code sample is C++, NOT C.  C++ supports reference parameters, but C only supports reference indirectly via pointers.

I agree that the second implementation is cleaner.  In order to make it work in C, change the `&` in each of the parameters to `*` and dereference each `x` and `y` (also with `*`) inside the function.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm aware that & is a C++ feature. I included C in the tags for the question because I thought it would appeal to pure C folks (if they even exists).

Comment: @Fast Fish: Please do not include tags with the intention of increasing your audience.

Comment: @dmckee, not sure I follow you. In my view, C programmers would be able to offer insight into this practice, given that the papers I referred to originally in my question were targeted at C, or using C. Increasing the audience is sensible for the purpose of reaching the right audience. There was no attempt to increase the audience for its own sake, if that is what you were speaking to.